# Unicode For Over and Under Line

Tags: unicode

I'm making a console application that has a progress bar. I'm using the █ character ([this one](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2588/index.htm)) for the "filled" part of the progress bar. For the "empty" part, I'm using _ (underscore) but it makes it look like this:

█████████_________________ 30%

Is there any unicode character that has an under and over line?

Comment: Try the [shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/) for this kind of searching.

Comment: Oh thats awesome, hadn't seen that before. Didn't really find anything close to what I want. I ended up printing a line of _ above the progress bar line. Works well enough.

Comment: There is a unicode overbar/overline character, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/41664207/6047827 and  https://stackoverflow.com/q/47087009/6047827