# Is there a way to overline text in (GitHub flavoured) Markdown?

Tags: github-flavored-markdown

I would like to overline some text in a Markdown file. Is this possible?

Comment: What is "a pin which is active low"?

Comment: That part isn't really relevant, I have removed it. It was suppose to be a bit of background on why I wanted to overline some text. In electronics, overline indicates that the signal line is "active low."

Comment: AFAIK there's no support for overline in github's markdown

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [the Combining Overline Unicode Character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0305) (U+0305) to simulate an overline, just paste this character after every character you want to overline:

`̅`

This produces the following result:

**1̅**

Alternatively, you can use [a generator](https://fsymbols.com/generators/overline/) for this.

Answer (score 15):

It can be using tildes (~~) like the same way as for bold, italic, etc. Below is the example from the [GitLab documentation](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/):

> Any word wrapped with two tildes (like ~~this~~) will appear crossed out.

Comment: The question is asking about overline (drawing a line above the text), not strikethrough (drawing a line through the text).

Comment: Strangely enough, I ended up searching for "overline" while what I actually wanted is "strikethrough". So I would say this answer is helpful.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [GitHub Flavored Markdown Spec (section 4.6)](https://github.github.com/gfm/#html-block) it should be possible using inline HTML tags with *style*.

For example,

```html
<span style="text-decoration:overline">SIGNAL_ACTIVE_LOW</span>
```

should be rendered with the text
overlined.

This works in a lot of markdown editors that adhere to CommonMark specs, and "GFM is a strict superset of CommonMark", but it seems don't works.

You can try in the [CommonMark reference implementation](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/).

[image]

**UPDATE:**
It don't works in markdown files like "README.md", but works in GitHub Pages, as you can se below:
[image]

Comment: But it doesn't work here. Like in: at all. Is `<span style="text-decoration:overline">overlined</span>` after "with the" intended to be hidden or not?

Comment: Ehi! You are right! It don't works....
But according to the iGFM Spec it should work: https://github.github.com/gfm/#html-block.
I'll edit my answer.